# I want to add a product to cart programatically to cart when a product has custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, custom-options, addtocart, programmatically

I want to add a custom product(eg :cooler) to cart programmatically to cart when a product has custom option(as ice packing) or the cart items have custom option(as ice packing) and update the quantity of the custom added product  if the total quantity of the products that have custom option  is greater than some limit.

In my case if a product has ice packing  as custom option and if the product as added to cart and add a product cooler to the cart and if the quantity is less than 12 then add 12 pint cooler and id it is greater then 12  then add 24 pint cooler .if it is greater than 24 the add a 12 and 24 pint cooler(ie 2 products) to cart, if greater than 36 remove 12 pintcooler and update the 24 pint cooler quantity  to 2 and if greater than 48 tha add one 12 pint to the 24 pint cooler(2 qty) and so on..

Please help me to do this  and please provide the code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. add product attribute required_ice_pack  in the install script

```
if (!$this->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'required_ice_pack')) {
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'required_ice_pack', array(
        'group' => 'General',
        'type' => 'int',
        'input' => 'select',
        'label' => 'Required Ice Pack',
        'global'=> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'required' => false,
        'attribute_set' => 'Default',
        'source'  => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'default' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'is_configurable'=>false,
    ));

}
```

2. add this in config.xml, section global. for access to attribute from quote

> ```
> <sales>
>   <quote>
>         <item>
>             <product_attributes>
>               <required_ice_pack/>
>             </product_attributes>
>         </item>
>     </quote>
> </sales>
> ```

3. add observer for event **checkout_cart_save_after**

```
 public function observerMethod()
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

        $qty =0
        //calculate Qty
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getIceStorage())) {
                // add code for calculate qty, for product required ice pack 
                $qty+=$item->getQty();
            }
        }

        // calculate qty ice pack

        $icepackAQty = $icepackBQty = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getSku()=='sku_icepack_a_product') {
                $icepackAQty+=$item->getQty();        
            }

            if ($item->getProduct()->getSku()=='sku_icepack_b_product') {
                $icepackBQty+=$item->getQty();        
            }
        }

    }
```

4. for add product to cart you can use

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
```

5. for remove icepack

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem($quoteItemId);
```